# Magento How to Export/Import all products from all store in a single fetch/dump?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can be able to import products CSV to all store from admin back end in a single shot. Also Export all products of all store in a single shot in admin back end.

If any extension available or if not means how we can achieve this using coding?

Consider I have three stores in a sites like this

1. www.store1.example.com
2. www.store2.example.com
3. www.store3.example.com

So will admin user able to export all products in this three domain in to single csv also import it to at a time in all domain?

Comment: How many products do you have in your catalog to be exported and how many products do you want to import.

Comment: @Muk each site may have around 5K to 10K products same for both import and export

Comment: Try this>> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html

Answer (score 2):

Using the SSH command-line avoids the web call timeouts. I've used this code to enable SSH command-line execution of exports:

```
<?php
#$profileId = 1; #All Products
$profileId = 16; #OnSale
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('[ERROR] Invalid ID');
}
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
?>
```

You'd need to change `$profile = XXX` to suit your profile ID.

Then, from SSH, call `php export.php`.

I haven't tried making this work for imports though.

Comment: above you suggested for system->import/export->data flow profiles,   what about system->import/export->export

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have tried doing with default functionality

> magento admin -> system -> Import/Export.

for more idea you can first try exporting products csv & then taking its reference you can make your csv for importing.

Comment: Is it possible to run admin -> system -> Import/Export by command line, because website shows time error for more than 20k products.